# NSMutableArray seems to be prematurely releasing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add Annotations to an array to place multiple pins on a map.  I have everything in a for loop.  The first time it loops through, it adds the object to the array just fine.  When it goes back through... the array has 0 objects in it.  Can anyone tell me why?

EDIT: I'm using ARC.

```
-(void)plotMultipleLocs {
float latitude;
float longitude;
NSRange commaIndex;
NSString *coordGroups;
for (int i=0; i<=cgIdArray.count; i++) {
    coordGroups = [cgInAreaArray objectAtIndex:i];
    commaIndex = [coordGroups rangeOfString:@","];
    latitude = [[coordGroups substringToIndex:commaIndex.location] floatValue];
    longitude = [[coordGroups substringFromIndex:commaIndex.location + 1] floatValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    MKCoordinateRegion reg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1000, 1000);
    self->mapView.region = reg;
    MKPointAnnotation* ann = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    ann.coordinate = loc;
    ann.title = [cgNameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    ann.subtitle = [cgLocArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableArray *mutAnnArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:annArray];
    [mutAnnArray addObject:ann];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a mutable array within the loop and adding your object to it.

At the next iteration of the loop, you create a new mutable array and add a new annotation to it.

Leave aside the fact that you are creating it from another array rather than just adding your annotation to `annArray`

Basically, the array that you are adding objects to last as long as one iteration, and then goes out of scope.

Try moving the array out of the loop:

```
-(void)plotMultipleLocs {
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    NSRange commaIndex;
    NSString *coordGroups;

    NSMutableArray *mutAnnArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:annArray]; // Create one array outside the loop.

    for (int i=0; i<=cgIdArray.count; i++) {
        coordGroups = [cgInAreaArray objectAtIndex:i];
        commaIndex = [coordGroups rangeOfString:@","];
        latitude = [[coordGroups substringToIndex:commaIndex.location] floatValue];
        longitude = [[coordGroups substringFromIndex:commaIndex.location + 1] floatValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
         MKCoordinateRegion reg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1000, 1000);
         self->mapView.region = reg;
         MKPointAnnotation* ann = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
         ann.coordinate = loc;
         ann.title = [cgNameArray objectAtIndex:i];
         ann.subtitle = [cgLocArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [mutAnnArray addObject:ann]; // Add the annotation to the single array.
    }

// mutAnnArray will go out of scope here, so maybe return it, or assign it to a property
}
```

Comment: Yeah... My coworker figured it out right before I refreshed the page.  Haha.  Thanks for the answer though.  I'll mark it for you so you get the rep.

Comment: I'm creating another array from annArray because if I declare annArray as an NSMutableArray, and just try to use that it doesn't work.  I get 0 objects in the array.  annArray is an ivar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retaining the instance to avoid it being released?

Comment: I'm using ARC. It yells at me if I retain it. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Every time through the loop, you create a new mutable array with the contents of a different array. The mutable array containing the object you added on the previous iteration is not kept.